# cannot get $(this) to work in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Hey guys so I am trying to have a overview product function work for all the queried post in wordpress.
Here is my set up:

```
<?php $i = 0; $j = 1;?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
      $postid[$i] = get_the_ID();
      echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$postid[$i]."' id='hiddenpostitle".$j."' name='hiddenpostitle'/> ";
      echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$j."' id='hiddenpostnumfield'/> ";
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
           $('.item-post a').click(function() {
                 var num;
             $(this).num = $('#hiddenpostnumfield').val();
                 var prodname ;
             $(this).prodname = $('#hiddenpostitle' + num).val();

                 $.post('overviewcheck-515adfzx8522', { 
                      'ProdName': prodname
                 },
                 function( response ) {
                 },
                 'json'
            );
         });
         $('.item-post a').colorbox({
                 opacity:0.3, 
                 href:"../overviewa512454dzdtfa"
         });
    });
 </script>              
<?php 
         $i++;
     $j++;
    ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

So this will get a bunch of post from wordpress and paste them to page, the JQuery code is then suppose to get the specified prodid based on which post is clicked from the `.item-post a`

When I run this I get the very last post, than nothing happens - for instance `1,2,3,4,5` it would pick always 5.

Let me know if this makes sense, I don't think I am properly using the $(this).  But not to sure, if you could give me a hand I would appreciate :)

UPDATED:

```
<?php /*query_posts('test');uncategorized*/ $i = 0; $j = 1;?>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
                    $postid[$i] = get_the_ID();
                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$postid[$i]."' id='hiddenpostitle".$j."' name='hiddenpostitle'/> ";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$j."' id='hiddenpostnumfield'/> ";
                ?>

                <?php 
                $i++;
                $j++;
                ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function()
                                {


                                   $('.item-post a').each("click" ,function(e) {
                                         $(this).click(function(e) {


                                        var num;
                                        num = $('#hiddenpostnumfield').val();
                                    var prodname ;
                                    prodname = $('#hiddenpostitle' + num).val();

                                       $.post('overviewcheck-515adfzx8522', 
                                        { 
                                            'ProdName': prodname

                                        },
                                        function(response) {
                                        },
                                        'json'
                                    );
                                    });
                                   });
                                    $('.item-post a').colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"../overviewa512454dzdtfa"});
                                });

                            </script>
```

I get a error saying click has no method 'apply'

Okay so Wordpress querys post -

```
<?php /*query_posts('test');uncategorized*/ $i = 0; $j = 1;?>
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
                        $postid[$i] = get_the_ID();
                        echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$postid[$i]."' id='hiddenpostitle".$j."' name='hiddenpostitle'/> ";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$j."' id='hiddenpostnumfield'/> ";
                    ?>

                    <?php 
                    $i++;
                    $j++;
                    ?>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This creates an input field - 2 hidden ones with an incrementing value so hiddenpostitle1, hiddenpostitle2 , etc... and hiddenpostnumfield value will increase 1,2,3,etc. As the post are posted.  Than the JQuery code will get which image, (image-post a ) is selected, than that sends to file that creates the session based on data passed and the colorbox opens it up in a overview look.

MY ISSUE:

I cannot get the right data passed based on what prod they select.  No matter what it is always the last post put on site.

Okay so now we are getting somewhere!!!

Check it out in action go to prodjsoundlighting.com - and click images but still buggy and not to sure why.

here is updated code:

```
<?php /*query_posts('test');uncategorized*/ $i = 0; $j = 1;?>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
                    $postid[$i] = get_the_ID();
                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$postid[$i]."' id='hiddenpostitle".$j."' name='hiddenpostitle'/> ";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$j."' id='hiddenpostnumfield".$j."'/> ";
                ?>

                <?php 
                $i++;
                $j++;
                ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function()
                                {


                                   $('.item-post a').each(function(i) {
                                         $(this).on("click", function(e) {


                                        var num;
                                        num = $('#hiddenpostnumfield' +(i+1)).val();
                                    var prodname ;
                                    prodname = $('#hiddenpostitle' + (i+1)).val();

                                       $.post('overviewcheck-515adfzx8522', 
                                        { 
                                            'ProdName': prodname

                                        },
                                        function(response) {
                                        },
                                        'json'
                                    );
                                    });
                                   });
                                    $('.item-post a').colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"../overviewa512454dzdtfa"});
                                });

                            </script>   

So now it is putting up, but it is taking like 3 above what it is suppose...best way is to see it so check it out and let me know.
```

Comment: What is `$(this).num` supposed to do? Perhaps you meant `$(this).data('num', ...)`?

Comment: What kind of url is this? `overviewcheck-515adfzx8522`

Comment: The url is part of wordpress it just does it that way.

Comment: @DavidBiga: Wat? So why is that code in there?

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: @blender check the site out and let me know if you got any ideas...its the homepage images.

Comment: Sorry i had to crash last night and couldn't help you resolve this. Altho if you're doing anytype of "feed", wouldn't it be better to create a php backend that creates an XML with RSS layout and then just use a a jQuery plugin ([*like this one at this jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/Pp44S/)) to call in the feed as needed

Comment: That is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$(this)` incorrectly. `$(this)` points to the element that triggered the function, so in your case the clicked `$('.item-post a')`.

Also, nothing to do with `$(this)`, your code runs through a loop but creates a load of inputs with the same `id` - `hiddenpostnumfield`. `id`'s should be unique within a page.

Comment: No each input field get a unique number by the increment of j and i

Comment: Okay, but it doesn't `<input type='hidden' value='".$j."' id='hiddenpostnumfield'/>`

Comment: check out site I posted in edit, let me know if you got any ideas how to fix it.